# Javascript handling multiple IDs

Tags: php, javascript, html, slidedown

I'm completely new in javascript. The problem is, I have multiple textarea and div which 'echo'-ed out via PHP with ID (for example textarea_1,textarea_2...), and I wanna do something like, when the textarea is on focus, only that particular textarea which being focussed will slide down and expand.

Html

```
<textarea id="comment_textarea_1"></textarea>
<div id="button_block_1"><button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" id="cancel_1">Cancel</button></div>

<textarea id="comment_textarea_2"></textarea>
<div id="button_block_2"><button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" id="cancel_2">Cancel</button></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $textareaID = $this.attr("id").replace("comment_textarea_");
    var $buttonblockID = $this.attr("id").replace("button_block_");
    var $cancelID = $this.attr("id").replace("cancel_");

    var $textarea = $('#'+$(textareaID));
    var $button = $('#'+$(buttonblockID));
    var $cancel = $('#'+$(cancelID));

$textarea.focus(function(){

    $textarea.animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast" );
    $button.slideDown("fast");
    return false;
});

    $cancel.click(function(){
    $textarea.animate({"height": "18px",}, "fast" );
    $button.slideUp("fast");
    return false;
});
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: So what is the trouble? You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Opps sorry for that. The textarea is not sliding down when onfocus. The main problem is that I have 2 identical textareas with different IDs (as you can see above), but I need the javascript to handle both textareas, although both textareas have different IDs. @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained it in the code. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // select all the textareas which have an id starting with 'comment_textarea'
   var $textareas = $("textarea[id^='comment_textarea']");
   $textareas.on("focus",function(){
      // now $(this) has the focused element
      $(this).animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast" );
      // find the button block of this div and animate it
      $("div[id^='button_block']",$(this)).slideDown("fast");
   });

   $textareas.on("focusout",function(){
      // now $(this) has the focused out element
      $(this).animate({"height": "18px",}, "fast" );
      // find the button block of this div and animate it
      $("div[id^='button_block']",$(this)).slideUp("fast");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you're attempting. Please let me know if the following is the effect you're after:

```
$("[id^='comment_textarea_']").on({
    focus: function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: '85px' }, 750).next().slideDown();
    },
    blur: function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: '20px' }, 250).next().slideUp();
    }        
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwype/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. The above answers are concentrating on using ID's... The last time I checked this is one of the main reasons we have the class attribute?

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.comment-textarea').focus(function()
    {
        $(this).animate(
        {
            'height' : '85px'
        }, 'fast');
        $(this).next('.button-block').slideDown('fast');
    }).blur(function()
    {
        $(this).animate(
        {
            'height' : '18px'
        }, 'fast');
        $(this).next('.button-block').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<textarea id="comment_textarea_1" class="comment-textarea"></textarea>
<div id="button_block_1" class="button-block"><button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" id="cancel_1">Cancel</button></div>

<textarea id="comment_textarea_2" class="comment-textarea"></textarea>
<div id="button_block_2" class="button-block"><button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" id="cancel_2">Cancel</button></div>
```

And a little fiddle to show it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/ngYMh/